# Shortest path from source to and from a negative cycle using Bellman Ford

Tags: python, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

I would like to find the shortest path from a source node in the graph to a negative cycle without walking over any cycle twice. **If there is a definitive answer to this, please answer. Otherwise, I would like to show how I have approached the problem in the hope that others may show me where I have erred.**

Below is a simplified version of my code which implements the Bellman-Ford algorithm to detect negative cycles (using [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/)). This is a straightforward implementation of the algorithm. I discuss my alterations to it further along.

```
class NegativeWeightFinder:
  def __init__(self, graph: nx.Graph):
    self.graph = graph
    self.predecessor_to = {}
    self.distance_to = {}

  def initialize(self, source):
    for node in self.graph:
      # Initialize all distance_to values to infinity and all predecessor_to values to None
      self.distance_to[node] = float('Inf')
      self.predecessor_to[node] = None

    # The distance from any node to (itself) == 0
    self.distance_to[source] = 0

    def bellman_ford(self, source):

      self.initialize(source)
      for i in range(len(self.graph) - 1):
        for edge in self.graph.edges(data=True):
          self.relax(edge)

      for edge in self.graph.edges(data=True):
        if self.distance_to[edge[0]] + edge[2]['weight'] <
          self.distance_to[edge[1]]:
          yield self._retrace_negative_loop(edge[1])
```

I have also implemented a method to retrace negative loops:

```
def _retrace_negative_loop(self, start):
  loop = [start]
  while True:
    next_node = self.predecessor_to[next_node]
    # if negative cycle is complete
    if next_node in loop:
      loop = loop[:loop.index(next_node) + 1]
      loop.insert(0, next_node)
      return loop
```

I would like to find the least-weighted path from and to each negative cycle in the graph. I believe this could be accomplished by, after completing the negative cycle,

1. iterating over the second-least-weighted path to source (as the first leads to a negative cycle).
2. To go from the cycle to the source (instead of from source to cycle), I added a predecessor_from data structure, which tracked the shortest path from each node to source (whereas predecessor_to tracks the shortest path from source to node).

I created a hacky data structure to track the least-weighted paths from each node to and from source, which basically functions like a priority queue allowing only unique elements (the highest priority of two equal elements takes precedence over the other). The code for this "priority set" is below

```
class PrioritySet:
  def __init__(self):
    self.heap = []
    self.popped = {}

  def add(self, d, pri):
    heapq.heappush(self.heap, (pri, d))

    return True

  def pop(self):
    popped = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
    while popped[1] in self.popped.keys():
      # Raises IndexError if done popping
      try:
          popped = heapq.heappop(self.heap)
      # for debugging
      except Exception as e:
          raise e

    self.popped[popped[1]] = popped[0]
    return popped

  def peek(self):
    # self.heap[0][1] is the name of the element
    try:
      while self.heap[0][1] in self.popped.keys():
        # Raises IndexError if done popping
        heapq.heappop(self.heap)
    # for debugging
    except Exception as e:
      raise e

    return self.heap[0]

  def reset(self):
    for key, value in self.popped.items():
      heapq.heappush(self.heap, (value, key))
    self.popped = {}

  @property
  def empty(self):
    for elem in self.heap:
      if elem[1] not in self.popped.keys():
        return False

    return True

  def __str__(self):
    return str(list(self.heap))

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)

  def __len__(self):
    total = 0
    seen = set()
    for elem in self.heap:
      if elem not in self.popped and elem not in seen:
        total += 1
        seen.add(elem)

    return total
```

Here is my implementation of this algorithm:

```
class NegativeWeightFinder:

    def __init__(self, graph: nx.Graph):
        self.graph = graph
        self.predecessor_to = {}
        self.distance_to = {}
        self.predecessor_from = {}
        self.distance_from = {}

        self.seen_nodes = set()

    def initialize(self, source):
        for node in self.graph:
            # Initialize all distance_to values to infinity and all predecessor_to values to None
            self.distance_to[node] = float('Inf')
            self.predecessor_to[node] = PrioritySet()
            self.distance_from[node] = float('Inf')
            self.predecessor_from[node] = PrioritySet()

        # The distance from any node to (itself) == 0
        self.distance_to[source] = 0
        self.distance_from[source] = 0

    def bellman_ford(self, source):
        self.initialize(source)
        # After len(graph) - 1 passes, algorithm is complete.
        for i in range(len(self.graph) - 1):
            # for each node in the graph, test if the distance to each of its siblings is shorter by going from
            for edge in self.graph.edges(data=True):
                self.relax(edge)

        for edge in self.graph.edges(data=True):
            if self.distance_to[edge[0]] + edge[2]['weight'] < self.distance_to[edge[1]]:
                yield self._retrace_negative_loop(edge[1], 
                                                  source=source)
    def relax(self, edge):
        if self.distance_to[edge[0]] + edge[2]['weight'] < self.distance_to[edge[1]]:
            self.distance_to[edge[1]] = self.distance_to[edge[0]] + edge[2]['weight']

        # no matter what, adds this edge to the PrioritySet in distance_to
        self.predecessor_to[edge[1]].add(edge[0], self.distance_to[edge[0]] + edge[2]['weight'])

        if self.distance_from[edge[1]] + edge[2]['weight'] < self.distance_from[edge[0]]:
            self.distance_from[edge[0]] = self.distance_from[edge[1]] + edge[2]['weight']

        self.predecessor_from[edge[0]].add(edge[1],
                                           self.distance_from[edge[1]] + edge[2]['weight'])

        return True

    def _retrace_negative_loop(self, start, source=''):
        arbitrage_loop = [start]
        if source not in self.graph:
            raise ValueError("source not in graph.")

        # todo: i do not remember to which edge case this refers, test to see which then specify in the comment.
        # adding the predecessor to start to arbitrage loop outside the while loop prevents an edge case.
        next_node = self.predecessor_to[arbitrage_loop[0]].peek()[1]
        if unique_paths and next_node in self.seen_nodes:
            raise SeenNodeError(next_node)

        arbitrage_loop.insert(0, next_node)

        # todo: refactor this so it is not while True, instead while not next_to_each_other
        while True:
            next_node = self.predecessor_to[arbitrage_loop[0]].peek()[1]

            # if this edge has been traversed over, negative cycle is complete.
            if next_to_each_other(arbitrage_loop, next_node, arbitrage_loop[0]):
                arbitrage_loop.insert(0, next_node)
                arbitrage_loop = arbitrage_loop[:last_index_in_list(arbitrage_loop, next_node) + 1]



                self.predecessor_to[arbitrage_loop[0]].pop()

                def _pop_arbitrage_loop(loop, predecessor):
                    while predecessor[loop[0]].empty:
                        loop.pop(0)

                # add the path from source -> min_distance_to_node to the beginning of arbitrage_loop
                while arbitrage_loop[0] != source:
                    _pop_arbitrage_loop(arbitrage_loop, self.predecessor_to)
                    next_node = self.predecessor_to[arbitrage_loop[0]].pop()[1]
                    # if this edge has already been traversed over/ added to arbitrage_loop, must exit the cycle.
                    if next_to_each_other(arbitrage_loop, next_node, arbitrage_loop[0]):
                            self.predecessor_to[arbitrage_loop[0]].pop()
                        # this prevents an error where every edge from a node has been traversed over.
                        _pop_arbitrage_loop(arbitrage_loop, self.predecessor_to)

                        next_node = self.predecessor_to[arbitrage_loop[0]].pop()[1]

                    arbitrage_loop.insert(0, next_node)

                # add the path from arbitrage_loop[-1] -> source to the end of arbitrage_loop
                while arbitrage_loop[-1] != source:
                    next_node = self.predecessor_from[arbitrage_loop[-1]].peek()[1]
                    if next_to_each_other(arbitrage_loop, arbitrage_loop[-1], next_node):
                            self.predecessor_from[arbitrage_loop[-1]].pop()

                        arbitrage_loop.append(next_node)

                    self.reset_predecessor_iteration()
                    return arbitrage_loop

                arbitrage_loop.insert(0, next_node)

    def reset_predecessor_iteration(self):
        for node in self.predecessor_to.keys():
            self.predecessor_to[node].reset()
            # predecessor_to and predecessor_to have the same keys
            self.predecessor_from[node].reset()

def next_to_each_other(li: list, *args):
    for i in range(len(li) - (len(args) - 1)):
        for j in range(len(args)):
            if li[i + j] != args[j]:
                break
            if j == len(args) - 1:
                return True
    return False


def last_index_in_list(li: list, element):
    return len(li) - next(i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(li), 1) if v == element)
```