# How to implement the fastest way to find the lengths of all shortest paths from one source node and detect negative cycles at the same time in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, graph-theory, bellman-ford

Entire Problem I am trying to solve: [Rich Cows](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fwwuCgtQwppgQe0uL1bPWkR-69KNQhsNk7zybuqBUdk/edit?usp=sharing).

Right now I have a problem that needs me to identify the shortest path from one node to all others using a given graph.
Some details:

1. This is a weighted graph that can have both positive and negative edge lengths.
2. The source node is always 1.
3. There can be negative cycles in this graph.
4. The program is to output the string "-INFINITY" if that is the shortest path.

After some research on other questions, I settled on the Bellman-Ford algorithm. It was one of the only algorithms that could find negative cycles.
However, some other questions do not answer mine either. For example:
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320943/how-to-find-shortest-paths-with-k-negative-weighted-edges) ignores negative cycles while [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542806/shortest-path-from-source-to-and-from-a-negative-cycle-using-bellman-ford) deals with a python implementation, not the language I use, C++.

However, its time complexity did not meet the requirements. Is there any other way or algorithm that can perform the same calculations as my code below while working faster? Or is there any way to optimize Bellman-Ford and my code below? I am sure that the problem is the algorithm because I tested the times of the input, initialization, and output. They were all reasonably short.

My code is below. I tried to end the algorithm when it didn't change anything, along with the second run of it to find negative cycles. I also added lines like `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);` However, while the changes were helpful, it didn't solve the problem. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
struct Edge {
    long long from = 0;
    long long to = 0;
    long long weight = 0;
};
long long n = 0, m = 0;// n = number of vertices, m = number of edges
std::deque <Edge> trails; // collection of paths
std::deque <long long> dist; // the end result from the source to each of the other nodes
void bellmanford() { // part 1 of my goals
    dist[1] = 0; // set source to 0
    for (long long i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        bool changed = false; // no change initially
        for (long long j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (dist[trails[j].to] > dist[trails[j].from] + trails[j].weight) { // check if its better than the previous path
                dist[trails[j].to] = dist[trails[j].from] + trails[j].weight; // update
                changed = true; // if something changes, we keep going because another change could happen
            }
        }
        if (changed == false) { return; } // if nothing occurs, more runs would be useless, so end
    }
}
void negativeCycleCatcher() { // part 2 of my goals
//this is pretty much the same thing as the bellmanford function except it changes nodes to -INFINITY
    for (long long i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        bool changed = false;
        for (long long j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (dist[trails[j].to] > dist[trails[j].from] + trails[j].weight) {
                dist[trails[j].to] = -2147483647;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        if (changed == false) { return; }
    }
}
int main () {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    std::cin.tie(0), std::cout.tie(0);
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    trails.resize(m);
    dist.resize(n + 2, 2147483647); // initialize all distances with a large number
    for (long long i = 0; i < m; i++) { std::cin >> trails[i].from >> trails[i].to >> trails[i].weight; }
    bellmanford(); // find shortest paths
    negativeCycleCatcher(); // find negative cycles and nodes with -INFINITY
    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // output results
        if (dist[i] == -2147483647) { std::cout << "-INFINITY"; }
        else { std::cout << dist[i]; }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Negative edge lengths are a killer to efficiency. Is there no way to represent them except as negative weight?

Comment: @GemTaylor The sad part is that there is indeed no way. Negative weights must be calculated as negative weights. If I could somehow turn them all into positive, then Dijkstra's algorithm would have sufficed. That is the reason I went for Bellman-Ford.

Comment: I guess the next question is how many negative weights. For a very small number of negative arcs it is probably easy. I haven't read the Johnson trick in detail, but it looks like you do a full djikstra on the positive arcs, then discard any negative arcs that don't improve, and for the others, re-run djikstra from there over the top of the existing results until you don't make any improvements. But yes the cycle detection is a pain. I guess you have to tag the paths to the entrypoints of the negative nodes. And then if two negative arcs improvement regions overlap then you have more fun.

Comment: @GemTaylor Well, thank you for your suggestions and responses, but the input varies. For all I know, all arcs could be negative.

Comment: To answer your question, the fastest way to implement is to find an existing code and copy it.  You can also try using exiting libraries or reusing code that you already have.  I recommend designing the code before you implement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I edited the question title to make my goals more clear. I don't need a typing class teaching me how to write out the code the fastest way. Rather, I would like to find out how to write the code that performs best in the function I want it to serve.

Comment: Well, thank you for your suggestions and responses, but the "fast" part I am looking for refers to runtime, not the time I spend sitting down and writing the code.

Comment: " its time complexity did not meet the requirements"  So, what is the time requirement?

Comment: *I also added lines like ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);* -- What does this have to do with basic algorithms and algorithmic complexity?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie At that point I was doing anything and everything to try to get my code running faster to help the overall problem of my code going past the time limit. However, the main slowness comes from the run of Bellman-Ford.

Comment: @ravenspoint 2 secs for 10000 nodes and 15000 one-way paths.

Comment: @Hudson -- The code you have has all the earmarks of a question from a "competitive coding" website.  If this is the case, have you used that site to search for successful submittals?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That observation is correct. So far, I can't find a solution there...

Comment: So what is going to happen is this: we post an answer with code; you are going to copy/paste it on the challenge site; you get an error from a test case that fails; you tell us that our answer doesn't work. I don't think I will play this game. Maybe post the link to the challenge, cite the code challenge verbatum; provide all test cases for which your code fails or exceeds the time limit.

Comment: " identify the shortest path"  your code does not do that.  It merely outputs the  length of the path.

Comment: If you need to use `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); ...` to get your code to run fast enough to be within the time limit with your C++ program, the site is probably expecting you to use a different approach. Without access to the original problem description there's no way to identify this though...

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Do you want to find the paths, as your question title states, or do you want to find only the lengths of the paths, as your code does.

Comment: Why are you using `std::deque` rather than `std::vector` for `trails` and `dist`?

Comment: @Luatic Thanks for your response. Is that a serious problem there? I used to only use vector until once encountered a problem where I needed both pop_front() and pop_back(), and so for convenience I just kept using it in case that happened again.

Comment: @Hudson I would assume that a deque will add overhead compared to just a vector since it has to support more operations efficiently (i.e. I would assume that a deque needs to allocate free space on both ends, whereas for a vector free space on one end suffices).

Comment: @Luatic Thank you so much! I got it working now. That was extremely helpful. It does turn out that my program loaded all that unnecessary stuff space and functions. You should put that in an answer for the bounty.

Comment: @Hudson You're welcome :) added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `std::deque` rather than `std::vector` for `trails` and `dist`. Try switching to a `std::vector`.

Asymptotically this may be irrelevant since both are typically implemented using dynamic arrays; the operations on a `std::deque` have the same (or better, for operations which prepend or remove elements at the front) asymptotic time complexities.

A deque will however add overhead compared to just a vector since it has to support more operations efficiently; for example, I would assume that a deque needs to allocate free space on both ends, whereas for a vector free space on one end suffices.

In general, when implementing algorithms, try to be as frugal as possible: Use the simplest and most efficient (not just asymptotically) data structures. Appending to a linked list may have the same asymptotic (amortized) time complexity as appending to a `std::vector`, but due to allocation overhead, appending to a `std::vector` is usually more efficient (both memory- and speed-wise). Or, for another example: Augmenting a tree-based sorted set to hold ranks (counts) doesn't affect the time complexity either, but worsens the constant factors. If you don't need the ranks, use a sorted set which isn't augmented.